# Haskell: Are list comprehensions higher order functions?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I have an assignment where we are not supposed to use any higher order functions, could a list comprehension be classified as a higher order function?

Comment: I think this is debatable enough that in reality, only whoever made the assignment can tell whether it's allowed.

Comment: I can't say yes but I can't say no either; list comprehensions aren't functions (should be safe to use for your assignment).

Comment: My feeling is that the restriction "do not use higher order functions" could be meant to force students into using explicit recursion. It's not crystal clear, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A list comprehension in Haskell is just syntactic sugar. It is defined in the Haskell 2010 Report [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) like so:

```
[ e | True ]          = [e]
[ e | q ]             = [ e | q, True ]
[ e | b, Q  ]         = if b then [ e | Q ] else []
[ e | p <- l, Q ]     = let ok p = [ e | Q ]
                            ok _ = []
                        in concatMap ok  l
[ e | let decls, Q ]  = let decls in [ e | Q ]
```

Note the use of `Q`, which ranges over qualifiers (which can include functions), in the patterns. So the answer is yes, a list comprehension is higher-order.

Comment: One possible translation (assuming no language extensions) is given in the [List Comprehensions](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11) section of the Report, and does not mention `Monad` at all; it does use `concatMap`, which happens to be similar to the bind for the monad, but it can be completely independent. Of course `concatMap` is just as much a higher-order function as `(>>=)` is.

Comment: @DanielWagner I got my information from [this wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension). But the report, of course, should be the basis for judgement. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @d3dave Using higher order functions to define something does not make it higher order. I can say `ys = map f xs`, which uses `map` which is higher order, but that does not make `ys` higher order.

Comment: @Abhay: yes, but `Q` in the list comprehension ranges over qualifiers, which can include functions, and is used in the `ok` function. So it would be more correct to mention the usage `Q` in the pattern perhaps.

Comment: I mean to say, whatever is used inside, the result of a list comprehension is a list. And a list is a non-function value, so order-zero.

Answer (score 1):

”Higher order" has a specific meaning. If a function takes an argument which is a function (or returns a function), the former is said to be higher order. (For example: map.)

List comprehensions are expressions representing list values, not functions. So the answer is: No.